# Is there any software for testing sequences for non-randomness in Java?

Tags: java, testing, random, statistics

I looking for a program or library in Java capable of finding non-random properties of a byte sequence. Something when given a huge file, runs some statistical tests and reports if the data show any regularities.

I know three such programs, but not in Java. I tried all of them, but they don't really seem to work for me (which is quite surprising as one of them is by NIST). The oldest of them, [diehard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests), works fine, but it's a bit hard to use.

Comment: What test are you specifically looking to run?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? Are you trying to see if the file could be further compressed? Its a great question, I'm just curious. :D

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/569/best-way-to-determine-if-a-list-of-bytes-are-random

Comment: Actually, all I can get. I'd like to test and tune a PRNG, so any observable pattern is bad. The tuning is the reason why I want to integrate it in the program. It's neither homework nor serious work, just something I'm interested in.

Comment: to tune a PRNG, use a stndard chi-square test....but then again a PRNG with well known param values, should not need to be 'tuned'.

Comment: @Mitch: Thx for the link. A chi-square is just one of many tests. When trying to make a new PRNG, there are no well knows param values.

Comment: @maaartinus: The problem is this statement "When trying to make a new PRNG": this is expert territory. What's wrong with existing ones with well known characteristics? Creating your own PRNG is like creating your own encryption scheme; it's almost certainly going to be flawed.

Comment: I know, that's a too complicated problem for most peaple including myself. And no, there's nothing wrong with existing PRNGs and neither I'd recommend anybody using their own invention. However, trying to make it is a way to learn something, and I enjoy it more than reading still more and more papers. I'm really not gonna use it for anything critical.

Comment: @maaartinus, this is a highly theoretical problem: starting off: Knut's bible vol2 "3.5 - What is random sequence?" There are practical tests to confirm if your generator fails but you have to start w/ the theory 1st.

Comment: what didn't you like about the three programs you tried?  In what way did they not work?

Comment: 1. None of them is in Java, 2. Except for Diehard they loved to crash. 3. They're no libraries and embedding them in my program would be hard, even calling them as external program and parsing their output would be no fun.

Comment: Actually I think this is an interesting project. Personally I would be that interested in a PRNG, but a program that could test it would be a good learning tool.

Answer (score 4):

As some of the commenters have stated, this is really an expert mathematics problem. The simplest explanation I could find for you is:

[Run Tests for Non-randomness](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35d.htm)

[Autocorrelation](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35c.htm)

It's interesting, but as it uses 'heads or tails' to simplify its example, you'll find you need to go much deeper to apply the same theory to encryption / cryptography etc - but it's a good start.

Comment: Out of those referred to on this page autocorrelation is probably the easiest to implement.

Comment: @biziclop: Thanks, I've added a direct link to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be using [Fuzzy logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic). You can extract fuzzy associative rules from sets of data. Those rules are basically implications in the form:

if A then B, interpreted for example "if 01101 (is present) then 1111 (will follow)"

Googling "fuzzy data mining"/"extracting fuzzy associative rules" should yield you more than enough results.

Your problem domain is quite huge, actually, since this is what data/text mining is all about. That, and statistical & combinatorial analysis, just to name a few.

About a program that does that - take a look at [this](http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~frans/KDD/Software/FuzzyAprioriT/fuzzyAprioriT.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not so much an answer to your question but to your comment that `"any observable pattern is bad"`. Which got me thinking that randomness wasn't the problem but rather observable patterns, and to tackle this problem surely you need observers. So, in short, just set up a website and crowdsource it.

Some examples of this technique applied to colour naming: http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/ and http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Nathan_Moroney/color-name-hpl.html